# PHP Backslash in input type and value

Tags: php, input, backslash

Beginner learning PHP and just working my way through a book which teaches the basics of PHP coding and MySQL databases.

I've come across a section on building a shopping cart and I was wondering what the purpose of the backslash is in the following code (the book does not explain). Please explain in simple terms.

```
<?php
echo ' <input type=\"text\" size=\"3\" name = \"qty[{$row['item_id']}]\"
```

Comment: it's called escaping and in this case, it's not required when echo'd in single quotes. Double quotes, yes; not singles. The quotes then appear as double quotes in HTML source.

Comment: In other words; doing `echo "<input type=\"text\" size=\"3\" name = \"qty[{$row['item_id']}]\">";` would be considered as valid syntax, while `echo "<input type="text" size="3" name = "qty[{$row['item_id']}]">";` would throw a syntax error.

Comment: I see...Thanks for the explanation.